# NextJS 14 - How to modify a request to access in the page

Tags: next.js13

I am using nextjs 14 and have a requirement of passing certain confidential information about the requesting user to the Page. I am using middleware.js like:

```
export function middleware(request){
...
}
```

Here I access the request object to check for certain HTTP headers, authenticate the user and accordingly allow to proceed with the requested URL.
Additionally, I want to use certain information about identifying the user in my Page, to use some server actions to provide customized experience to the user like:

```
import React from "react";
const pullSpecialData = async () => {
  //identify the user 
}
export default async function Page() {
  const data = await pullSpecialData();
  return <div className="bg-red-50">This is a page {data}</div>;
}
```

Here only params & searchParams are available. Coz the request object is not available on Page, I can't really do this. Any workaround for this?